# JQuery Datepicker inverse next and prev buttons events

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I want to inverse Jquery datepicker next and prev buttons events, so that when press at next decrements the date and vise versa to fitting arabic right to left direction.

this is my sample code.

```
 $("#searchFromDate").datepicker({
        showOtherMonths: true,
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: false,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        monthNames: ['كانون الثاني', 'شباط', 'آذار', 'نيسان', 'أيار', 'حزيران',
        'تموز', 'آب', 'أيلول', 'تشرين الأول', 'تشرين الثاني', 'كانون الأول'],
        dayNames: ['احد', 'اثنين', 'ثلاثاء', 'اربعاء', 'خميس', 'جمعة', 'سبت'],
        dayNamesShort: ['احد', 'اثنين', 'ثلاثاء', 'اربعاء', 'خميس', 'جمعة', 'سبت'],
        dayNamesMin: ['احد', 'اثنين', 'ثلاثاء', 'اربعاء', 'خميس', 'جمعة', 'سبت'],
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#searchToDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
    //searchToDate
    $("#searchToDate").datepicker({
        showOtherMonths: true,
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: false,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        monthNames: ['كانون الثاني', 'شباط', 'آذار', 'نيسان', 'أيار', 'حزيران',
        'تموز', 'آب', 'أيلول', 'تشرين الأول', 'تشرين الثاني', 'كانون الأول'],
        dayNames: ['احد', 'اثنين', 'ثلاثاء', 'اربعاء', 'خميس', 'جمعة', 'سبت'],
        dayNamesShort: ['احد', 'اثنين', 'ثلاثاء', 'اربعاء', 'خميس', 'جمعة', 'سبت'],
        dayNamesMin: ['احد', 'اثنين', 'ثلاثاء', 'اربعاء', 'خميس', 'جمعة', 'سبت'],
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#searchFromDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
```

Comment: see my edit. just update the css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the plugin file and find the ID's which it uses to depict prev and next buttons; and invert those IDs where the plugin is trying to inject the HTML.

But your arrow images should point it the existing direction, for that, again invert the arrow styles for the 2 ID's(just the background attribute)

**EDIT:** You just need to override the css as:

```
.ui-datepicker-prev
{
    left:0px;
    right:2px;
}

.ui-datepicker-next
{
    left:2px;
    right:0px;
}

.ui-icon-circle-triangle-w
{
    background-position:-80px -192px;
}

.ui-icon-circle-triangle-e
{
    background-position:-80px -192px;
}

.ui-icon-circle-triangle-w
{
    background-position:-48px -192px;
}
```

Comment: I dont want to invert the whole plugin i need to inherit or add custom script to do this specific action.